# Phoenix: pattern matching params in contexts (atoms and strings)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following function definitions, and I'm trying to find a way to simplify the params so that they're all uniform.

```ex
  def update_user(%User{} = user, %{password: _} = attrs) do
    attrs = Map.put(attrs, :password_reset_token, nil)
    update_user(user, attrs, &User.password_changeset/2)
  end

  def update_user(%User{} = user, %{password_reset_token: _} = attrs), do:
    update_user(user, attrs, &User.password_reset_changeset/2)

  def update_user(user, attrs), do:
    update_user(user, attrs, &User.changeset/2)

  def update_user(user, attrs, changeset) do
    user
    |> changeset.(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
  end
```

A programmer could mess that up I think, by passing in a map with string keys (say for `%{"password" => value}`) and it'd match with `update_user/2`. So maybe I should update the params for those functions? Or use a guard on `update_user(user, attrs)` to not match w/ `%{"password" => value}`?

Contrast with the following, which takes params straight from a controller function (`def create(conn, params)`):

```ex
  def authenticate_user(%{"email" => email, "access_token" => _}) do
    case get_by(%{email: email}) do
      %User{} = user ->
        {:ok, user}
      nil ->
        {:error, :non_existent}
    end
  end

  def authenticate_user(%{"email" => email, "password" => password}) do
    with %User{} = user <- get_by(%{email: email}),
      {:ok} <- verify_password(password, user.password_hash),
      do: {:ok, user}
  end
```

Those params are matching with a map that has string keys. As I mentioned I'm doing that because then I can pass `params` straight from the controller and pattern match with what's been passed in (in this case, various login methods). Is there a standard Phoenix way for tackling this kind of problem?

Comment: One way would be to convert all atom keys to string keys and then do the pattern matching only on strings. Another way is to use `cond`, e.g. `cond do attrs["password"] || attrs[:password] -> # password exists ...`. I'd rather just call the function with string keys so only a single pattern match is needed (since you cannot change the behavior of `params` having string keys).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using pattern matching.

It might not the most beautiful solution, but I don't think matching for both string and atom keys ever is.

```elixir
  def update_user(%User{} = user, attrs) do
    user
    |> user_changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
  end

  def user_changeset(user, attrs) do
    case attrs do
      %{"password" => _} ->
        User.password_changeset(user, Map.put(attrs, "password_reset_token", nil))

      %{password: _} ->
        User.password_changeset(user, Map.put(attrs, :password_reset_token, nil))

      %{"password_reset_token" => _} ->
        User.password_reset_changeset(user, attrs)

      %{password_reset_token: _} ->
        User.password_reset_changeset(user, attrs)

      _ ->
        User.changeset(user, attrs)
    end
  end
```

Also, you could pattern match the function arguments for all cases, but I think that's messier in this case.

Another option would be to first always transform all `attrs` maps into string keys (the reverse, dynamically generating atoms is generally considered a bad idea).